# Phase 10 probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

*Assuming there are $96$ basic numbered cards, two of each rank from $1$ through $12$ in each of four colors (Blue, Green, Red and Yellow) in the deck.*

> What is the probability of being dealt a set of $4$ and a run of $4$, if I am to be dealt $10$ cards in total?

The problem for me is that I am over counting. I only know how to solve the problem assuming each card is unique, this is not the case as there is two of every card. A sample set would be a hand with at least four $5$'s and a sample run would be a hand with $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$.

Comment: Just make every card unique by calling half of them A and half of them B.  You now have eight colors.  To get a set of four you choose four of the eight.  You need to account separately for cases where the set of four is also part of the run and where it is not.

Comment: You mean both a set of 4 and a run of 4 in the same hand, right?

Comment: yes  this is correct @saulspatz